# Minimum number of nodes to reach all leaves

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-algorithm

Suppose I have a list that defines if a user (A-G) has admin access to a site (1-6):

```
 A: [1,2,3]
 B: [2,3,4]
 C: [3,4,5]
 D: [4,5,6]
 E: [1,2]
 F: [3,4]
 G: [5,6]
```

I would like to get some data from each site, using the minimum number of different user credentials. In the example above, a solution would be to use users A and C.

I have thought of modelling the problem to graphs, so the user-site list would be a forest where each site is a leaf.

I've thought of adding a root that connects to all user nodes and running BFS, but that doesn't give the optimal solution. I've also thought about using union find, and it seems to work in some examples that I've ran, however I'm unsure in the correctness of my solution.

I've also considered using max-flow for this problem, but that doesn't seem to be the right direction.

I also don't think that a greedy algorithm would solve this :(

An awful visualization:

[image: An awful visualization]

Comment: I think this is the *set cover* problem, your search engine will be of assistance.

Comment: Yep, you're right, thats the exact problem

Comment: Now that we've identified the correct algorithm for this problem this question isn't terribly useful here on SO.  I think the decent thing to do is to delete it before it attracts dust.